# What PHP chunk of code is FASTER?

Tags: php, compression, minify

We all know that xHTML/CSS and JS minification and compression benefits large traffic sites.

Take a look at the following code:

```
include("template.funcs.php");
include("country-redirect.php");
if(($country=='PL')||($country=='POL'))
{
    header('Location: index_pol.php');
    exit();
}
$include_path = './global_php/';
$page = "couture";
include $include_path."shop.inc.php";
$movie_num = 1 ;
```

Now see the minifed version:

```
include("template.funcs.php");include("country-redirect.php");
if(($country=='PL')||($country=='POL')){header('Location: index_pol.php');
exit();}
$include_path='./global_php/';$page="couture";include $include_path."shop.inc.php";
$movie_num=1;
```

Which one do you think is faster - in general, I want to start also minifying my programming too, small var and string names like $a rather than $apple and trying to remove as much extra character as possible. Will the PHP Compiler like a compressed chunk or spaced out one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will the PHP Compiler like a compressed chunk or spaced out one?

It does not matter. Any difference between these will be in the microseconds at best.

Making code readable is the only thing that matters.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. So even if I have a PHP file called index.php with about 5000 line breaks and a hello world echo at the bottom, it will still load fast?

Comment: The amount of parse time saved by minifying PHP code is going to be absolutely microscopic. Unless you're a prolific commenter who writes "War & Peace" type epic comments for every line of actual code, you will NOT see any useful difference in load/parse times unless you're running a facebook-sized operation.

Answer (score 5):

PHP code stays on the server, so it's size is essentially irrelevant.

Removing those newlines is a *really bad* idea. Make your code readable for humans.

Comment: So basically I can have PHP files; function files with indentation, comments and includes and libraries and classes within these files in include libraries and it sits server side so the user is never effected?

Comment: The only thing the user (browser) sees is what is output by your PHP. How you layout the PHP code itself is irrelevant.

Comment: I meant the performance aspect. Even though it is server stored. For example imagine an include file 100mb then an echo hello world vs an echo without the include.

Comment: If you have a one-line PHP file that just prints "hello", versus _a humongously large framework of intricate code structures and heavy initialization with database checks and everything_ that just prints "hello", then yes, the first one is very likely going to be faster. If the difference in _actual_ source code is a single file versus code reasonably split in a few headers _but the same amount of work_, the difference is only going to be in how fast your OS reads the files. Which will amount to nothing for a reasonable setup.

Answer (score 4):

PHP doesn't care if your code is minified or not.

Write code so you can edit it cleanly later.  Minification has no measurable impact on performance.

The reason that you see minified CSS/JavaScript is not for parsing/execution speed... it is for cutting down the file size for data transfer.  Your PHP is processed server-side.  The only thing that is sent is the output of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The minified version won't be faster for 2 reasons:

- The script is not sent to the client, but interpreted, and then the result
  is sent
- Minifying a php script has very little impact on performance

If you want to seed up your php code, you can install a [php accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, minification of PHP code will make no real difference in execution speed. That is the answer to your question, but I think that this quote is also relevant:

> Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you live.

Please don't minfiy the primary version of your code. Please don't use variable names like `$a` instead of `$apple`. The ability to read and understand your code is far more valuable than any space savings or marginal speed increase that you may get from minification.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when the PHP engine parser does its magic on your code it automatically removes all white space and comments any ways. The difference would be maybe 1/10 of a second if you start getting up in the megabytes worth of text. But this is simply the webserver parsing the files.

If you want real over head ideas search Google for "Best PHP Practices" and get into good habits. I can see from your above snippet you might need some. Just some advice.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't matter, as it's not transfered by internet to the client.